# How to show selected value in dropdowm menu

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a problem, I want to show the user the selected value the user has selected before.

I have a `custom post` type I have created and I have also a separate plugin that's using a custom db.

What I have done is make the dropdowm menu with all the custom posts (show posts name) and then the user choose what custom post they need to get the post link. Then I copy the post permalink into var and uptade the permalink into plugins DB.

Here is the code that print all `custom post type`

```
<select class="edit-link-field" name="link[<?php echo $id ?>]">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'test_reviews',
                'position' => 'pastor'
            );
            $pastorList = new WP_Query($args); while ($pastorList->have_posts()) : $pastorList->the_post();
            $postID = get_the_ID();
                $is_selected = (get_the_title() == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                echo '<option value="'.get_permalink( ).'" '.$is_selected.'>'.get_the_title().'</option>';

            endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
            $test = get_permalink( );

            ?>         
  </select>
```

So what I need now is the same dropdown menu but with selected value that the user selected. and if the user will change the select value and will push on the "update button" it will update the new permalink to DB

Comment: i think your select won't dispaly the selected item since you're matching the title instead of the permalink :
`$is_selected = (get_permalink() == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';`

This is the option value that should be checked.

Comment: Hi, as i say this dropdown menu work fine. when i add new record and choose from the dropdown menu some post by name and then click on the "add" it takes the permalink of the post and update the DB. i can see this link on DB so this work fine. the problem is when i want to edit my choose. first i need to see what i have selected before so in edit mode the dropdown value must be selected. and then if i change it to another post i want on "update" click to update my DB with the new permalink.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see where you're loading the previously selected value, where does `$selected` get set? and if you're saving the permalink, why are you trying to match the title to the selected value? also, saving the ID would be far more reliable, as IDs don't change while permalinks can.

Comment: Hi Milo, "I don't see where you're loading the previously selected value" that's what i asking. i don't know how to show this value so it will be selected.

for the other question i will try to explain myself better. my plugin is create table with some fields. for example:
1. car photo, 2.car name, 3.car info 4.etc.. so i have created drop down menu that shows custom post type. near every car. now i want to choose for some car custom post type that have full review for this car. thats why i need to store in DB the permalink of the custom post type.

Comment: in the front i can call to my table by shortcode(id) and it will print the table fields. one of the files can be text or image that need to hold the post permalink that choose before in the admin section. for example: click here for full review.thanks for help!

Comment: you don't show how you're saving the selected value, how is anyone supposed to tell you how to load it? we don't know where or how you're storing that data. and I will reiterate: permalinks can change, post IDs never do. if you store permalinks you run the risk of links breaking because you're storing an old version of the permalink. storing the ID and looking up the permalink when it's output on the front end will prevent this, and will also consume far less space in your database.